# TWIG condition for full URL

Tags: drupal, twig, field, drupal-8

This code does not work.

```
{% if url == 'example.com/categoty' %}
some text
{% endif %}
```

How to do this?

Comment: how to do what?

Comment: How to write that condition for url correct?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code. Verify your variable with `{{ dump(url) }}`

Comment: Don't you have a typo in your string (`categoty` instead of `category`) ?

Comment: No, I have a category mysite/news and when I turn to the next page of this category - mysite/news?page=1, some text should not be displayed. I have already tried everything, it does not work.

Comment: I checked {{dump (url)}}
The result is NULL
How to solve this problem? I have no ideas

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't have url variable assigned. There is a global parameter for that:

```
    {% if app.request.requestUri == '/categoty' %}
        some text
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Try dumping requestUri and check if it is '/category' `{{ dump(app.request.requestUri) }}`

Comment: Checked. The result is NULL. How to fix it?

Comment: My bad. Using drupal current uri can be accessed using `url('<current>')`  instead of `app.request.requestUri`.

Comment: It works, but how to set the condition now? `{% if url('<current>') == 'example.com/category' %}
                        some texts
                    {% endif %}` This code does not work

Comment: Dump variable again `{{ dump(url('<current>')) }}` and then compare the value in your condition.

Comment: It something wrong with URLs on my site. After dump, it turned out that's what `array(3) { ["#markup"]=> string(23) "http://example.com/category" ["#cache"]=> array(3) { ["contexts"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "route" [1]=> string(8) "url.site" } ["tags"]=> array(0) { } ["max-age"]=> int(-1) } ["#attached"]=> array(0) { } } `

Comment: Good. Then `{% if url('<current>')['#markup'] == 'http://example.com/category' %}
        some text
    {% endif %}`

Comment: Same. Some text displayed on every next page.

Comment: Then maybe all your pages has the same uri? Can you paste it from the adress bar? I found in your other comment that it would be like `/news?page=1` so then `{% if url('<current>')['#markup'] == 'http://example.com/news?page=1' %} some text {% endif %}`

Comment: Does not work. As I understand the problem with my routes, Error - Route http://example.com/category does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if 'mysite/news' in url %}

some text

{% endif %}
```